# Finding the variable of a Canvas Element in unobfuscated Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working with a GameMaker Studio and exporting a game in HTML5.

A missing feature in GameMaker Studio is the ability to export an image of the screen to the photo album of iOS and Android devices.

My workaround idea is to use a 3rd party plugin for HTML5 that will allow me to save a Canvas.

However GameMaker obfuscates the final output of the javascript and canvas it creates.

All I need to do is find which global variable contains the Canvas and I can capture it.

I have gone through a sample of unobfuscated Javascript but I can't read the code well enough to know which global variable I am supposed to use to call the canvas in question (and I don't want to override the context of it will wipe the canvas).

I found where the Canvas is attached to the context. Can anyone help here?

A sample looks like this:

```
_j61.prototype._q61 = function () {
    _C8 = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    if (_C8) {
        this._yr = new _e9._B9._ua();
        this._yr._Gp(_C8);
        this._yr._Jp(1.0 / this._xW);
        this._yr._Rp(0.1);
        this._yr._Mp(1.0);
        this._yr._Bp(_e9._B9._ua._2q | _e9._B9._ua._3q);
        this._Fm._xr(this._yr)
    }
};
```

In my function (for example) what goes here?

```
HELPME.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
HELPME.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

Comment: `fillStyle` and `fillRect` are both methods of the _2D Rendering Context_, so the only thing that could possibly make sense here (if we are only looking at the code excerpts you have shown), is of course `_C8`, because that is the only 2D rendering context to be found anywhere.

Comment: When Game Maker exports an HTML file, you can see that the canvas is there and has an ID. This means you should be able to access the canvas via normal DOM methods like `getElementById`, gets its context, and stuff like that. You don't have to use the same reference that GM does.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol.  We must be aware that multiple `canvas.getContext`'s will always deliver a reference to the same GM context--not new different contexts.  So you can only use the same context that the GM does and therefore must be aware of the current context state created by the GM. ;-)